# Automatically log out user when token is invalidated

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have a SPA that is built on vuejs. When a user is logged in via API, the token is stored in local storage.

I need a global solution which will logout and prompt the user when the token is no longer valid. At the moment, I get "invalid token" error when accessing private API endpoints.

**How do I rig axios so that ALL response of invalid tokens will trigger the logout/prompt code?**

Comment: are you using `vuex` ?

Comment: @SrinivasDamam Yes I am

Comment: https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-set-timer-idle-in-vue-1f4b57beb886

Answer (score 0):

Here is an simple example with `axios`. It use a Bearer token for authentification.

```
import axios from "axios";

import { useUserStore } from "@/store/userStore";

const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: "",
  headers: {},
});

apiClient.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  async (error) => {
    const config = error?.config;

    if (error?.response?.status === 401) {
      const result = await refreshToken();

      if (result) {
        config.headers = {
        ...config.headers,
        authorization: `Bearer ${result?.token}`,
      };
    }
    return axios(config);
  }
);


const refreshToken = async () => {
  /* do stuff for refresh token */
 
  // if refresh token failed
  try {
    useUserStore().actionLogout();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    loacalStorage.clear();
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

you can write a function that clears your local storage after some time and logout user

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).